# json after success return undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using JS with Angular came to the following problem.

I am getting data from a requestService, so a call the request function and then do something with the data in a 'success' function. Inside this function, everything is fine and I get all my results but as soon as a leave the success function, my results are undefined. I read some other questions/answers about similar problems, and tried other things. However I do not really know how to hand this and wanted to ask this explicitly with a code example:

```
function loadShips() {
      var count = 0;
      RequestService.getShips(nelat, swlat, nelong, swlong, timestamp)
      .success(function(results) {
        var groupedShips = results.aisData.aisGroupedByShipType;
        _.each(groupedShips, function(groupedShip) {
          _.each(groupedShip, function(ship) {
            Markers['marker' + count] = createMarker(ship);
            count++;
          });
        });
        console.log(Markers, '#1')
        return Markers
      });
      console.log(Markers, '#2');
      return Markers;
    }
```

So anyone could maybe tell me, why Markers at the print out of '#1' are defined and at '#2' are undefined.

Comment: Which variable is undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the request is being done asynchronously, the call at #2 is happening before the request's `success` method is being called.  This would explain why the object does not exist yet.

One solution would be to pass a call back method into the factory as a parameter, and then call that method after the request success has occurred.  That would look something like this:

```
function loadShips(callBack) {
    var count = 0;
    RequestService.getShips(nelat, swlat, nelong, swlong, timestamp)
        .success(function(results) {
            var groupedShips = results.aisData.aisGroupedByShipType;
            _.each(groupedShips, function(groupedShip) {
                _.each(groupedShip, function(ship) {
                    Markers['marker' + count] = createMarker(ship);
                    count++;
                });
            });
        console.log(Markers, "#1");
        callBack(Markers);
    });
}
```

Using this method looks like this:

```
function myCallback(markers){
    console.log(markers, "#2");
    //assign markers to something
}

loadShips(myCallback);
```

Comment: Basically you will need to wait to use that object until after the success method is called.  It's hard to say specifically how to to do that without seeing what you're actually trying to do with that object

Comment: this is just a factory. Afterwards I call this method in my controller to set markers on a map. But again, the Markers are undefined in the controller when I call this function

Comment: Ok, I suggest adding a callback method parameter to the factory call, which you would then fire after the success call is made.  I will update my answer with the updated code.

Comment: Answer has been updated, let me know if you have more questions about it

Comment: yeah I have one more question. So now, when I want to use the 'Markers' I have to call loadShips(callBack) in my controller or the 'myCallback' function?

Comment: Basically you'll want to assign that Markers variable to a global variable that you can use in your code.  You'll need to make sure anything that needs to use that object is moved into a function that can be called from the `callBack` method, or is otherwise occurring after the assignment has been made to a global variable

Answer (score 1):

As Will P pointed out, with asynchronous functions, the inline code after them will execute first, because the success function is still waiting in the event queue.

in addition to that, Markers is being returned from inside a anonymous function which will not return it as the result of loadShips but will return it inside ajax wonderland, never to be seen.

what you will have to do is have a function that receives the data when it is ready and call that function with the data. I'm assuming things happen after the ships load, those things will have to be called after the anonymous function is done creating Markers.

```
function loadShips() {
    var count = 0;
    RequestService.getShips(nelat, swlat, nelong, swlong, timestamp)
    .success(function(results) {
      var groupedShips = results.aisData.aisGroupedByShipType;
      _.each(groupedShips, function(groupedShip) {
        _.each(groupedShip, function(ship) {
          Markers['marker' + count] = createMarker(ship);
          count++;
        });
      });
      doFancyWonderfulThingsInTheOcean(Markers);
    });
 }
```